# Haskell, Given two ints and return a list

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a function but I don't really know how to use recursion to implement it.. Could anyone give me some hint?

```
getList :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

And it has the following performance

```
getList 1 2 == [1,11]
getList 2 2 == [2,22]
getList 2 3 == [2,22,222]
```

Comment: Assuming the last `Int` in your signature was supposed to be `[Int]`, the base case is `getList n 0 = []`. Now find the general case of `getList n i` written in terms of `getList n (i-1)`

Comment: another small hint - you might find the function `\n -> n*10 + 1` interesting

Comment: @thatotherguy Sorry a typo.. Thank you and I will think more about it! :)

Comment: btw: does it have to be recursive? Because there is a nice implementation using things like take, map and iterate

Comment: @CarstenKönig Not necessary.. You've got any better idea? :)

Comment: as I said a combination of `take`, `map` and [`iterate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:iterate) (possible with something else I already mentioned) will yield this as an one liner - and if you join the `map` and `iterate` it will be even shorter. - If you want I can post the solution but I'll wait in case you want to experiment yourself.

Comment: Yiyue, are you asking us to do your homework? Your question does sound suspiciously like that, to be honest...

Comment: @DominiqueDevriese  Yes I admit that it's my homework. But it's not that simple and this is only a part of it which I'm stuck at :) besides I actually said something like give me just a hint :P... So I don't think I'm asking for answer :)

Comment: For future reference, it's okay to ask questions about homework, as long as you don't just copy the question into stack overflow and wait for the answer to come out (as you did now).  You should make an honest attempt at solving the problem yourself, and make your question show this.  You could for example include some of the things you tried already and indicate where you got stuck.

Comment: Also, I'm voting down your question because your question does not show any real attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @DominiqueDevriese Oh Thank you very much for your kind comment and advise! I will bear that in mind in the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function as I would put it:

```
getList :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
getList n m = take m $ iterate (\i -> (i*10) + n) n
```

if you want you can insert another step to make the parts even more distinct:

```
getList :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
getList n m = take m . map (* n) $ iterate (\i -> (i*10) + 1) 1
```

Comment: Thank you! One more thing that I suddenly thought of .. what if I only want `getNum :: Int -> Int -> Int` and it does `getNum 2 3 == 222`?

Comment: Oh I know what to do with my previous question :) Thank you again!

Comment: FWIW: I'm voting down your answer because you solved what is clearly a literal copy-past of a homework assignment instead of just providing a hint or asking the poster what he/she has tried already.